# My GTFL won't load with GLTFLoader: error Invalid typed array length: 55419

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf, react-three-fiber

I'm currently trying to load a model gltfLoader I've debugged what I can with some of the common errors.
I've made sure my gltf file is in the /public folder, I've also tried using and import with the path both give the same error:

`"Uncaught Could not load /scene.gltf: Invalid typed array length: 55419 "`

currently my flies look like this : [image]

I've tired to load the .gltf with different methods such as the useGLTF but i get the same issue. The network call has the scene obj correctly though here: [image]

the main file call in the ThreeD.jsx is wraped in a `<suspense/>` tag and then the `<Model/>` call i've also tried to import the model using `const Model = lazy(() => import("./Model"));`
but that seemed to get me no where on the main issue of the scene not loading. i grabed my flies from : https://sketchfab.com/3d-models?date=week&sort_by=-likeCount&cursor=bz0yJnA9NDA%3D

any help or ideas on what to debug would be amazing, im happy to provied any details needed.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and error trace!

Comment: will do that, sorry for the mistake will do better on my next question.

Comment: I recommend editing this question and answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Issue was i needed to have the entire 3d file in /public and i needed to lazy import the model file. [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As others wrote, please do not paste screenshots of your code. They're often unhelpful (e. g. can't be copy-pasted) and confusing (showing non-relevant parts like the IDE). Please paste your code as text instead and use the formatting possibilities provided.